# if not exist record checking

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to to something like if my database dont have the record, then insert it, the query below is my checking, the code have no errors, so i am not sure did i really make the checking ?

Record 1

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 1 )
INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
VALUES (1,'User','UserInfo')
```

Record 2

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 2 )
INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
VALUES (2,'User2','UserInfo2')
```

Comment: Your queries look good to me.  What is your question?

Comment: This is MS SQL Server, rather than MySQL as tagged, no? (as evidenced by the `[]` column enclosures)

Comment: is this checking good  enough? because it dont have error return to me, so i am not sure the code is correct or not

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: "queries look good to me" --- `INSERT` cannot be prepended with `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Couldn't you just run the insert anyways? If the records exists and you used a PK and (possibly) UK properly, it would insert if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, it will not because you violated a constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to get some type of return value, use a function or stored procedure and return a value.  E.g.,

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 1 )
   Return -1
Else
   INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
   VALUES (1,'User','UserInfo')

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 2 )
   Return -2
Else
   INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
   VALUES (2,'User2','UserInfo2')
```

If using just an adhoc query or the query window in SSMS, create a variable above that or just print the message.  If you use a variable with coded sql queries, you can get the return value back.

```
Declare @ErrorValues int;
Select @ErrorValues = 0;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 1 )
 BEGIN
   Select @ErrorValues = @ErrorValues - 1;
   PRINT '-1';
Else
   INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
   VALUES (1,'User','UserInfo')

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE WHERE AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID = 2 )
 BEGIN
   Select @ErrorValues = @ErrorValues - 2;
   Print '-2'; --or PRINT 'audit_log_type_ID of 2 already exists';
 END
Else
   INSERT INTO TBL_AUDIT_LOG_TYPE ([AUDIT_LOG_TYPE_ID],[MODULE],[ACTION]) 
   VALUES (2,'User2','UserInfo2')
```